# Python threading: Python gevent using long running C extensions

Tags: python, multithreading, gevent

I have a flask app that uses a large integer optimization GoogleOrTools. The underlying package is writen in C but there is a python API that I use to call it. When I get a very long running task it seems as if it blocks other tasks and server becomes unresponsive. The obvious solution is naturally to put in a different service. Which I will impliment when I have the time.

But I'm curious if there is something I'm missing as I read Python threading after every x lines of byte code the thread changes, which should allow the other process to take over? But does that also happen in the case of Gevent? Or if it is acturaly allowing the other threads, but it might greedyly capture all the resources?
It would be really nice if someone with some inside could tell me what is and is not posible.

Comment: Usually, when using gevent correctly and spawning the 'OR calculation' in another thread it shouldn't block.

Comment: check [Why do these threads fail to work in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64883962/why-do-these-threads-fail-to-work-in-parallel)