# Run threads simultaneously in python

Tags: python, multithreading

So, I'm trying to run 2 threads simultaneously.
My code looks like this:

```
from threading import Thread
def Main():
    n = 10
    k = 2
    max = n//k
    def firstfunc():
        for i in range(0, max):
            print(i)
    def secondfunc():
        for i in range(0, max):
            print(i+10)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    T1 = Thread(target=Main().firstfunc, args=()).start
    T2 = Thread(target=Main().secondfunc, args=()).start
    for thread in [T1, T2]:
        thread.join()
```

The error that throws:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [2], line 14
     11             print(i+10)
     13 if __name__ == '__main__':
---> 14     T1 = Thread(target=Main().firstfunc, args=()).start
     15     T2 = Thread(target=Main().secondfunc, args=()).start
     16     for thread in [T1, T2]:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'firstfunc'
```

I searched online and I consulted also stackoverflow's answers to similar questions, but nothing worked for me. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If you define a function inside of another function it doesn't become its attribute. Are you confusing it with classes?

Comment: Also this has nothing to do with threading.

Comment: Also, a heads-up, python's threads [aren't running in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64884072/4727702)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Main()` returns `None` because you don't return anything from it in your code. Thus `Main().firstfunc` is an error just like `None.firstfunc`, because `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'firstfunc'`.

In general, it's not possible to access local variables of functions (`n, k, max, firstfunc, secondfunc` are `Main`'s local variables), and they don't automatically become attributes of the function or its return value.

You can return the functions themselves:

```
def Main():
    n = 10
    k = 2
    max = n//k
    def firstfunc():
        for i in range(0, max):
            print(i)
    def secondfunc():
        for i in range(0, max):
            print(i+10)

    return firstfunc, secondfunc

if __name__ == '__main__':
    first, second = Main()
    T1 = Thread(target=first, args=())
    T2 = Thread(target=second, args=())
    for thread in (T1, T2):
        thread.start() # CALL the `start` method!
    for thread in [T1, T2]:
        thread.join()
```

Example output:

```
0
1
10
2
3
4
11
12
13
14
```

Answer (score 1):

The error says that there is because Main function return None and None dont have attirbute firstfunc and so on.

my suggestion just change to class like this:

```
from threading import Thread
class MyClass:
    n = 10
    k = 2
    border = n//k
    def firstfunc(a):
        global border
        for i in range(MyClass.border):
            print(i)
    def secondfunc(b):
        for i in range(MyClass.border):
            print(i+10)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    T1 = Thread(target=MyClass().firstfunc, args=())
    T1.start()
    T2 = Thread(target=MyClass().secondfunc, args=())
    T2.start()

    for thread in [T1, T2]:
        thread.join()
```